# Jenkins pipeline checkout based on parameter provided

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have Jenkins declarative pipeline and want to checkout a branch based on parameter provided

```
def envToBranch  = [:]
envToBranch['dev'] = 'develop'
envToBranch['stg'] = 'stage'
envToBranch['prod'] = 'master'

pipeline {

  parameters {
    choice(name: 'ENV', choices: ['dev', 'stg', 'prod'], description: 'Application environment')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                  branches: [[name: '<how-to-access-mapping-here>']],
                  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                  extensions: [
                    [$class: 'SparseCheckoutPaths',  sparseCheckoutPaths:[[$class:'SparseCheckoutPath', path:'ansible/']]]
                  ],
                  submoduleCfg: [],
                  userRemoteConfigs: [
                    [credentialsId: 'my-creds',
                    url: 'git@github.com:MyOrg/my-repo.git']
                  ]])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So how can I access a mapping within checkout directive? Am I able to do the same within `script` directive?

Comment: You mean accessing the branch? You can replace `'<how-to-access-mapping-here>'` with `"refs/heads/${envToBranch."${params.ENV}"}"`

Comment: You can also use Multibranch Pipeline job that was designed to work with multiple different branches. It keeps every branch in a separate view, which helps you investigating logs for a specific branch. (Instead of having a single history for all branches.)

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I think you should put your comment as an answer

Comment: @towel thanks for you answer as well